# build number maven plugin for Git repo

Tags: java, git, maven, svn, version-control

A project that was earlier on svn was recently moved to github after which i am facing this issue while creating a build. It fails to generate the build number with the below error

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (default) on project line-management: An error has occurred while checking scm status. Exception while executing SCM command. Error while executing command. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "D:\workspace\project_git\project_management"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
```

code of pom.xml

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://some.svn.url/</connection>
</scm>    
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>create</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <doCheck>true</doCheck>
                <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                <timestampFormat>{0,date,"yyyyMMddHHmmss"}</timestampFormat>
                <timestampPropertyName>buildNumVar</timestampPropertyName>
                <shortRevisionLength>10</shortRevisionLength>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Error: `Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "D:\workspace\project_git\project_management"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 1):

Your scm tag still contains the the connection string to your old svn repository.

You should provide the url of the new git repository here, for example `<connection>scm:git:https://github.com/your-git-repo.git</connection>`. For the details of the connection string, please check [here](https://maven.apache.org/components/scm/git.html).

Comment: You changed the scm connection to git and still get the error message `Cannot run program "svn"`?

Answer (score 0):

When you install the svn program (tortoise for example) you need to check the command line option. By default, that option is disabled. That worked for me.

Comment: I have removed the Spanish part of your answer as Stack overflow is an English-only site. If you want to contribute in Spanish, there is a Spanish version of Stack Overflow: https://es.stackoverflow.com/